# SSRS hostname - how do I find where it's pointing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, hostname

OK this one's got me wondering.

- I have a hostname reports.mydomain.com
- When I use this in the browser, it's pointing to an SSRS report manager interface
- There is no A-record or CNAME for this hostname in our DNS zone file
- How is this hostname being directed to the appropriate server?
- I need to know this as I'm trying to locate the source of a report that's part of this SSRS instance!

Comment: I'm looking at this, about how to configure a URL for Report Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx

Comment: OK so I know how to configure the URL now, but how is this being found on the DNS without any entry in the DNS zone file??  Something must be pointing to the DB server IP??  And I guess there must be some kind of Microsoft web server built into SSRS somehow?